# Rudin's exercise: showing that $(L^\infty)^*\neq L_1$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

> Let $L^\infty = L^\infty(m)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $I=[0,1]$. Show that there is a bounded linear functional $\Lambda\neq 0 $ on $L^\infty$ that is $0$ on $C(I)$, and that therefore there is no $g\in L^1(m)$ that satisfies $\Lambda f = \int_I fg \, dm$ for every $f\in L^{\infty}$. Thus $(L^\infty)^*\neq L_1.$

We may see $C(I)$ as a subspace of $L^\infty$. Taking any $f\in L^\infty \setminus C(I),$ we consider the direct sum $\mathbb Rf \oplus C(I).$ There we may define the following linear functional $ \Phi(cf+g) = c$, which is null over the subspace $C(I)$. Now I want to apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to obtain a linear functional defined all over $L^\infty$. But for that, we must first ensure that $\Phi\leq p,$ where $p: L^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a sublinear map. The most natural $p$ to take is $p = \|.\|_\infty$, but I am not being able to prove that $\Phi\leq p$.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try to extend an evaluation map instead.

Comment: @Mindlack what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Consider the linear $\ell: f \in C(I) \longmapsto f(1/3)$ and show it can be extended to $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Mindlack why would it be zero at $C(I)$? And how do I ensure that it is not dependent on the class representative of $f\in L^\infty$?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I missed that part. Hahn-Banach yields an extension of the map to $L^{\infty}$ anyway, and that one isn’t represented by an element of $L^1$. To use with your proof strategy, consider for instance $f=1(x \leq 1/2)$: then $\Phi(cf+g)$ is the discontinuity jump at $1/2$ so is bounded by $2\|cf+g\|_{L^{\infty}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will not work. The reason is that you need to let $p=||\cdot||_\infty$ in order for $\Phi$ to extend to a *bounded* linear functional. But this is impossible because $||cf+g||_\infty$can be bigger than $|c|$. For a counter-example, think of $f=\chi_{[0,1/2]}$ and choose $g\leq 0$ well.

To construct a functional that works, you should think more carefully about what is special about continuous functions. Your above idea doesn't use anything about them besides that they are a subspace. As a hint:

> A continuous function satisfies $\lim_{x^+\rightarrow0}f(x)=\lim_{x^-\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ so defined an appropriate functional on some subspace and apply Hahn-Banach.

Comment: I may take $W$ as the subspace of all functions whose lateral limits exists at $1/2$ (since taking at zero does not make sense from the left). I may define the linear functional as the difference of those values. Ok, it is zero on the continuous functions and bounded by the norm. But why it is not dependent on the class representative?

Comment: The notion of a limit existing doesn’t make sense until you’ve chosen a measurable representative. This means you should take the subspace of function with a measurable representative whose left and right limits exist and show that this does not depend on the choice of representative.